# Print column value if one column name is same in all tables using left join

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to echo any column value by using LEFT JOIN method where one column name is common in all the tables used in select query? Below in my code. I want to get 'app_id' value along with all the columns, but 'app_id' doesn't print anything. app_id column is available in all 4 tables used in this query. It prints all the rows that i want to show but app_id does not return any value.

```
<?php

session_start();

include('../../connect.php');

$date = strtotime("+1 day", time());
$cdate = strtotime("-7 day", time());
$finaldate = date('Y-m-d', $date);
$scdate = date('Y-m-d', $cdate);

//$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblapps WHERE journeydate >= '".$finaldate."' AND appstatus = 'On-Hold' AND process = 'yes'";

$sql = "SELECT * from tblapps
LEFT JOIN tblapps2 ON tblapps.app_id =   tblapps2.app_id
LEFT JOIN tblapps3 ON tblapps.app_id =  tblapps3.app_id
LEFT JOIN payments ON tblapps.app_id = payments.app_id
WHERE
tblapps.journeydate >= '$finaldate' AND tblapps.appstatus = 'On-Hold' AND tblapps.process = 'yes'";

$result = $connect->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["app_id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["journeydate"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Seeing multiple databases with numbers after them is usually a sign something's not right here. If you need partitioning, use MySQL table partitioning. Don't cobble together your own using multiple databases.

Comment: What do you mean `app_id` doesn't "print" anything? You are doing a `SELECT *` which means you will get ***4*** `app_id` columns back. There is no distinct `app_id` column in your result set because of that. Get rid of your awful `SELECT *` and choose which columns you want from each join'd table. Then reference that column by name. If you need more than one `app_id` column then you have to alias them `SELECT tblapps.app_id as app_id1, tblapps.app_id as app_id2, ....` Then do yourself a favor and never write `SELECT *` in production code again.